# What is the time complexity tf2 core library

Tags: ros, transform, tf2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello All,

Can anyone guide me to get the time complexity of tf2 core library?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/255698/what-is-the-time-complexity-tf2-core-library/) by [babu](https://answers.ros.org/users/29471/babu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-02-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There's a paper on tf here: http://wiki.ros.org/Papers/TePRA2013_Foote

tf2 has several optimizations but has most of the same structure. The majority of the changes were dependency cleanup etc. You can see the tf2 design here: http://wiki.ros.org/tf2/Design

Performance related changes from tf include:

- Adding support for static transforms. This avoids maintaining a time history, and providoes O(1) lookups.
- There is support for remote caches, reducing the need for multiple caches.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2017-02-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2